# Identifying primary key for a vote table

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I am working on a voting table design using Postgres 9.5 (but maybe the question itself is applicable to sql in general). My vote table should be like:

```
-------------------------
object | user | timestamp
-------------------------
```

Where `object` and `user` are foreign keys to the ids corresponding to their own tables. I have a problem identifying what actually should be a primary key.

I thought at first to make a `primary_key(object, user)` but since I use django as a server, it just doesn't support multicolumn primary key, I am not sure either about the performance since I may access a row using only one of those 2 columns (i.e. `object` or `user`), but the advantage this idea works automatically as a unique key since the same user shouldn't vote twice for the same object. And I don't need any additional indexes.

The other idea is to introduce an `auto` or `serial` id field, I really don't think of any advantage of using this approach especially when the table gets bigger. I need also to introduce at least a `unique_key(object, user)` which adds to the computational complexity and data storage. Not even sure about the performance when I select using one of the 2 columns, may be I need also 2 additional indexes for the `object` and `user` to accelerate the select operation since I need this heavily.

Is there something I am missing here? or is there a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django themselves recognise that the "natural primary key" in this case is not supported.  So your gut feeling is right, but django don't support it.

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys

> Relational database designs use a set of columns as the primary key
>   for a table. When this set includes more than one column, it is known
>   as a “composite” or “compound” primary key. (For more on the
>   terminology, here is an ​article discussing database keys).
>
> Currently Django models only support a single column in this set,
>   denying many designs where the natural primary key of a table is
>   multiple columns. Django currently can't work with these schemas; they
>   must instead introduce a redundant single-column key (a “surrogate”
>   key), forcing applications to make arbitrary and otherwise-unnecessary
>   choices about which key to use for the table in any given instance.

I'm less failure with django personally.  <strike>One option might be to form an extra column as a primary key by concatenating object and user.</strike>

Remember that there is nothing special about a primary key.  You can always add a `UNIQUE KEY` on the pair of columns and make them both `NOT NULL`.

You might find this example useful.

https://thecuriousfrequency.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/make-primary-key-with-two-or-more-field-in-django/

Comment: Thanks! is there an active django app or a simple way to design a Model for  a composite primary key?

Comment: Did it! Thanks Philip! the prbolem was solved when I added `primary_key=True` to the first column of the two. Since my `models.py` was generated using `manage.py inspectdb`, the `unique_together` field was aleady defined with a tuple containing the two columns. It seems like a hack an not a clean way, but at least works right on the postgres level.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution woulf be to have a `PRIMARY KEY (object, user)` and an additional index on `user`. The primary key index can also be used for searches for `object` alone.

Form a database point of view, your problem is that you use an inadequate middleware if it does not support composite primary keys.

You'll probably have to introduce an artificial primary key constraint and in addition have a unique constraint on `(object, user)` and an index on `user`, but your gut feelings that that is not the best solution from a database perspective are absolutely true.

Comment: Thanks for this quick and detailed answer, I upvoted for now, if no other answer targeting the django part, I will make this as an accepted answer.